# How to perform update in webapi using httpget

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

How to use HttpGet to perform Update operation in WebApi?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the code you have written so far, and explain how it doesn't work. We aren't going to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRUD

Create - POST 
Read - GET 
Update - PUT 
Delete - DELETE

For update you want to use httpput. On controller side you want the method to start with Put.

Comment: Thanks. Does this  mean that with GET methd I can't do any update or insert operation?

Comment: Technically you can but it is considered bad practice. HTTP GET calls should be idempotent and typically read only. In the case of a failed call httpget could be called multiple times and result in undesirable behavior.

Comment: @MukilDeepthi According to REST design principles you should use "GET" method for retrieving the data. I would recommend follow goods design practices.

Comment: Correct GET should only be used for data retrieval.